# Replacing cookies file doesn't change anything in google chrome

Tags: windows-7, linux, google-chrome, cookies

I have linux as my main environment and windows 7 intalled on my virtual machine. What I'm trying to do is replace Cookies file with another file to change my cookies.

I logged in with account A on fb in windows and account B on linux. I transfer file from windows which was in `C:\Users\gio\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` file called `Cookies` on my linux machine and replaced it in this directory `/home/gio/.config/google-chrome/Default`, but nothing changed. I closed chrome on linux and opened again but I was logged in on account B again. So my question is from which file does google chrome read cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a less crude way - [EditThisCookie extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog). It can export and import cookies, it should let you copy session from one system to another.

You can also use it to view cookies.

Comment: I want to cahnge cookies with copy and paste not  with extension. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Chrome indeed reads cookies from xxx\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookie.
But I think Chrome has a validation or encryption mechanism that cannot directly replace Cookie file.If directly replace Cookie file,Chrome will clear the Cookie file.